# Logstash issue with Java 11

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, java-11

I am trying to load mysql data to elasticsearch using logstash.
I tried almost every version of mysql-connector-java.jar but everything fails.
can someone help me regarding this?
which version of mysql-java-connector is used with java 11.

Comment: The documentation for the [current version](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) of the MySQL Connector/J says that it only supports Java 8, have you tried using Java 8?

Comment: but elasticsearch 7.2 version is recommendable with java 11, it shows warning message like java 8 will be deprecated soon if I use java 8.

Comment: But the connector you want to use is not compatible with Java 11, if you want to use it you will need to use Java 8 for it. You can use Elasticsearch 7.2 with Java 8 now, or run a logstash instance on a lower version of java without any problem.

Comment: @leandrojmp, thats the nice idea but, elastic and logstash is installed on the same computer. how do I manage tow java versions in the same computer? I have to install elastic on the different computer right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Elasticsearch 7 works fine with JDK 8 — see the [supported JVM matrix](https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_jvm). This will be the easiest way.
2. You might be able to split into multiple JDK versions on a host with some trickery, but you're off the beaten track. Either you could

   - change the configuration files to point to the right Java version (though that might be tricky with updates)
   - Set different `JAVA_HOME` for the different users running the services.

Also note that in Elasticsearch 7 the JDK is automatically bundled with the binary and if there is no `JAVA_HOME` set it will fall back to that one.